# In LLVM IR pass, how to extract an absolute path of the current Module?

Tags: llvm-ir

The title describes it all. I'm writing an LLVM IR module pass and need to know the absolute path to the source code corresponding to the current Module. I know how to extract the *name* of the source code (through getSourceFileName() in Module), but what I need is the full path to the source code including an absolute directory path. How can I find this one? If there's a workaround, that will work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm gonna answer my own question here. You can find how LLVM internally restores the absolute paths in `IR/CodeGen/AsmWriter/AsmWriter.cpp:emitRemarksSection()`. It basically restores the path of the source code with the current path that *clang* is running on now. The API function that does this is provided by LLVM already.

Referring to this, let's convert a Module's file name to its full path.

1. Get the filename.

> std::string Filename = M.getSourceFileName();

2. Convert it to a `char` vector.

> llvm::SmallString<128> FilenameVec = StringRef(Filename);

3. Make it into a full path.

> llvm::sys::fs::make_absolute(FilenameVec);

The file full path is stored right back to `FilenameVec`. You'll need to include `llvm/Support/FileSystem.h` to use `make_absolute()`.

You can try it by sticking the following code (properly) to any working IR pass.

```
#include <string>
#include "llvm/Support/FileSystem.h"
      
...

std::string Filename = M.getSourceFileName();   // e.g., Filename = aaa.c
llvm::SmallString<128> FilenameVec = StringRef(Filename);
llvm::sys::fs::make_absolute(FilenameVec);      // e.g., FilenameVec = /path/to/aaa.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @Gwangmu for asking & answering this question. To ensure the resulting full path doesn't contain relative components (e.g. /path/to/../aaa.c) and is consistent across platforms (e.g. incl. Windows), you can call the real_path function instead, then convert it to generic format. The whole snippet would look like:

```
std::string relFilename = M.getSourceFileName();   // e.g., relFilename = ..\aaa.c
llvm::SmallString<128> FilenameVec = StringRef(Filename);
llvm::SmallString<128> RealPath;
llvm::sys::fs::real_path(FilenameVec, RealPath);  // e.g., RealPath = \path\to\aaa.c  <-- in Windows
//
filesystem::path fp {string(RealPath)};
string genericFilePath = fp.generic_string(); // genericFilePath = /path/to/aaa.c
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack way to do that

```cpp
std::string CurrWorkPath = std::getenv("PWD"); 
std::string FullFilename = CurrWorkPath + "/" + M.getSourceFileName();
```

The environment variable `PWD` is equal to the current working directory of clang.